# Function to return a string in C. Why this return null?

Tags: c, string, function

How can i return a string for work with?
I dont know why this function arent working.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* test(){
   char A[100];
   scanf("%s", A);
   printf("A = %s \n", A);
   return(A);
}

main(){
    char* B;
    B = test();
    printf("B = %s \n", B);  // why this return (null)?
}
```

Comment: Also, please dont make `return` look like a function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of Why is my program with Undefined Behavior behaving like this?

Answer (score 5):

This is undefined behavior. It might return the "correct" value; it might as well do something completely different, crash the program, or worse. The reason why it is undefined behavior is as follows:

```
char* test(){
    char A[100];
    scanf("%s", A);
    printf("A = %s \n", A);
    return(A);
}
```

Here you declare an array of 100 `char` on the stack. Later you return the address to that memory. However, it was on the stack, so that memory is invalid now. You then assign this invalid memory pointer to `B`:

```
char* B;
B = test();
```

So on this line:

```
printf("B = %s \n", B);  // why this return (null)?
```

You have undefined behavior.

Instead, try this:

```
char* test() {
    char* A = malloc(100);
    scanf("%s", A);
    printf("A = %s \n", A);
    return A;
}
```

In this function, the memory is allocated on the heap instead. This way, the pointer you return is valid (also note that you don't need any parentheses around the `A` in `return A;`). Don't forget to free the memory again, though. You do it by calling this at the end of your program:

```
free(B);
```

Note that for your code, your compiler will likely emit a warning. It might say something like:

> returning address of local variable or temporary: A

Those warnings can help you find potential problems and debug your code. When a program isn't working, try resolving all the warning first.

Comment: Thanks, works fine.

Comment: char* A = malloc( 100 * sizeof(char) );  // is the right answer based on this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-memory-allocation-in-c-using-malloc-calloc-free-and-realloc/